# Learning parser in python

Tags: python, parsing

I recall I have read about a parser which you just have to feed some sample lines, for it to know how to parse some text.

It just determines the difference between two lines to know what the variable parts are. I thought it was written in python, but i'm not sure. Does anyone know what library that was?

Comment: While extremely vague, this question is, nevertheless, quite interesting. I am also curious as to whether there are such "self-learning" parsers (especially if they are written in python).

Comment: I know it's vague, but I haven't got a clue what to tell more about it.

Comment: @shylent There doesn't seem to be publicly available code for this problem, but some research has been done: See "An Efficient Learning of Context-Free Grammars" by Sakakibara, PDF at tinyurl.com/nrpmor.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.  I have learned a lot from the responses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you mean *[TemplateMaker](http://code.google.com/p/templatemaker/)*, I haven't tried it yet, but it builds on well-researched *longest-common-substring* algorithms and thus should work reasonably... If you are interested in different (more complex) approaches, you can easily find a lot of material on Google Scholar using the query "wrapper induction" or "template induction".

Comment: Yeah, this is what I had seen. Not really a parser, but it commes close ;)

Answer (score 2):

Conceivably you might mean [Reverend](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=81259)?

Comment: No, it's not really what is was looking for.